# How to access a nested property, defined as a string, without using eval?

Tags: javascript

I have an object which may or may not have nested objects and properties, and I want to access them using a string. Here's an example...

```
var obj = {
    inside: {
        value: 10,
        furtherInside: {
            value: 100
        }
    }
    // may contain other objects, properties, etc.
};
function getObjProperty(str) {
    return eval("obj." + str);
}
getObjProperty("inside.value"); // returns 10
getObjProperty("inside.furtherInside.value"); // returns 100
```

...But I'd like a solution that doesn't use `eval`.
How can this be done *without using eval*? I'm looking for the best/optimal/fastest solution.

Comment: You need to parse the string, then you can reference each property via `[]`.  This is what the DataTables library does with respect to the `mData` column property.

Answer (score 6):

How about something like

```
function getObjectProperty(obj, str) {
    var props = str.split('.')
    var result = obj;
    for(var i = 0; i < props.length; i++)
        result = result[props[i]];
    return result;
}
```

This code assumes your strings are always valid and the object passed into `getObjectProperty` has properties that nest to the level you target, but it avoids `eval`. You could make it more robust with checks for undefined, but that may be overkill for what you need.

Test code, using your example:

```
var a = {
    inside: {
        value: 10,
        furtherInside: {
            value: 100
        }
    }
    // may contain other objects, properties, etc.
};

console.log(getObjProperty(a, "inside.value")); // prints 10
console.log(getObjProperty(a, "inside.furtherInside.value")); // prints 100
```

Comment: Thanks, that's nice and concise!

Comment: I ran a test -- http://jsperf.com/0em2f6k6 -- and yours was 3x faster than the answer I posted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the brackets notation:

```
var obj = {
    inside: {
        value: 10,
        furtherInside: {
            value: 100
        }
    }
    // may contain other objects, properties, etc.
};

alert(obj['inside']['furtherInside']['value']);
```

Then you may even use string properties like "my property":

```
var obj = {
   "my property": 10
};

obj["my property"];
```

**EDIT:**

This is an approach (using brackets notation) to what you are asking for:

```
String.prototype.getVal = function(elem) {
    var segments = this.split('.');
    for (var i = 0; i < segments.length; i++) {
        elem = elem[segments[i]];
    } 
    return elem;
}

var obj = {
    inside: {
        value: 10,
        furtherInside: {
            value: 100
        }
    }
    // may contain other objects, properties, etc.
};
console.log("inside.furtherInside.value".getVal(obj));
console.log("inside.value".getVal(obj));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/luismartin/kphtqd54

Since this method getVal() is being assigned to the String prototype, you may use it anywhere, and I think the implementation is pretty neat and fast. I hope this approach also helps getting rid of the negative vote :/

Comment: This doesn't answer the problem - the string should be a single string, not multiple arguments. Also, your code doesn't work, as `inside`, `furtherInside`, and `value` are all undefined.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to enclose them with quotes

Comment: While I don't necessarily agree with your choice to modify `String.prototype`, editing your answer deserves a +1 in my book!

Comment: Ok thanks :). So why don't you agree? You'd add an extra functionality of your choice to any of your "stringified" references to your nested objects and their properties.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with, using some recursiveness...

```
function getObjProperty(obj, props) {
    if (typeof props === 'string') {
        if (props.indexOf('.') == -1) {
            return obj[props];
        } else {
            props = props.split('.');
        }
    }
    if (props.length == 1) {
        return obj[props[0]];
    } else if (props.length > 1) {
        var top = props.shift();
        return getObjProperty(obj[top], props);
    } else {
        return obj;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0em2f6k6/
...But it's not as fast as a simple for-loop. http://jsperf.com/0em2f6k6

Answer (score 0):

Although not vanilla JavaScript, another possibility is to use lodash's `_.get` function: https://lodash.com/docs#get.

```
_.get(obj, "inside.furtherInside.value");
```

It essentially does the same as @analytalica 's solution, except using a `while` loop (see the `baseGet` function in the [lodash code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lodash/lodash/3.10.1/lodash.js)), but it also allows strings or arrays (using the `toPath` function), and allows you to include a default.